# Genret pdf and display output in div porstion

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have create PDF in code-igniter and create PDF library after load this library and create one PDF PDF is created successfully and it open in my fully page. But i hop i will display this PDF in 500 by 500 div portion

controller:

```
class Print_pdf extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('pdf');
        $pdf = $this->pdf->load();
    }


    function index() {
        $this->load->view("report");        
    }
}
```

view file:

```
$this->load->library('pdf');
$pdf = $this->pdf->load();
$pdf->WriteHTML("<h1>hello</>");            

echo "<div id=d1  class=dd style='height:500px;width:500px;overflow:scoll;background:lime;color:red;'>";       

$pdf->Output();

echo "</div>";
```

Comment: You can load it in an iframe that has the required size and put in your page.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:500px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Here is an usage example of "Embeddable Google Document Viewer":
https://googlesystem.blogspot.de/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html